# Bruce Banner allows Avengers to use the powers of the Hulk despite being horrified by his actions

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, marvel

A recurring theme in the *Avengers* films is Bruce Banner's horror at the carnage that ensues whenever he transforms into the Hulk. For example, in *Age of Ultron*

- As the Avengers are flying home after their initial mission, he is visibly traumatized by the knowledge that the Hulk has just killed or maimed large numbers of Hydra soldiers. Witness his reaction as Thor casually quips about all the enemies that the Hulk has just ploughed through.
- During Stark's party, Romanoff refers to him as "the guy who avoids fighting because he knows he will win".
- At the farmhouse, Banner rejects Romanoff's advances on the grounds that it's not safe for anybody to live with him, being as he is at risk of turning into the Hulk at the drop of a hat.

Add to this that previous films reference Banner's suicide attempt, which was prompted exclusively by his desire to put an end to the threat to others that the Hulk represents.

But then, why does he keep on going to missions with the Avengers? Clearly, when the Avengers go on a field mission, they don't want Banner's intellect, they want the Hulk's strength and invulnerability. Banner  must be aware that accompanying the Avengers on a field mission carries a high probability of him turning into the Hulk and causing death and suffering to fellow human beings. Yet, he never says "I've had enough, I'm going to sit this one out, you guys are on your own", or anything to that effect. Why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he was saying "enough" at the end when he STOLE A QUINJET AND JETTISONED HIMSELF INTO NEAR-ORBIT. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 7):

Well, would you? Knowing that if you go on those missions, they might need you to save their lives? Would you sit aside and let them "handle" it? During the second Avengers movie, we see Banner on the QuinJet, waiting to be called into action, meaning he's only called if absolutely needed (he refers to it as a Code Green, if I'm not mistaken).
So he goes on field missions, because the good that comes from turning into the Hulk actually out-weights the bad.

Also, and outside the movie-universe, there is at-least one story when he does exactly that, and stays away from all trouble, letting the other heroes deal with the problems of the world and with Ultron, ending on all of their deaths... the story is [*Next Avengers: Heroes of Tomorrow*](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Next_Avengers:_Heroes_of_Tomorrow) in the end, they end-up needing the Hulk and only after he transforms, Ultron is defeated once and for all.